# Export number of Documents from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I use mongochef as a UI client for my mongo database. Now I have collection which consists of 12,000 records. I want to export them using the mongochef.

I have tried with the export option(available) which is working fine up to 3000 documents. But if the number of records gets increasing the system is getting hung up.

Can you please let me know the best way to export all the documents in a nice way using mongochef.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came to conclusion to use the mongo using terminal which the best way to use(efficient).

read about the primary and secondary databases and executed the following query:

```
 mongoexport --username user --password pass --host host --db database --collection coll --out file_name.json
```